# Effective email with Salesforce

Tags: email, case, email2case

We would like our employees to send emails starting from an Account/Contact/Lead (not from cases) and be able to handle answers from clients.

Our current setup includes:

1. A different email address per internal employee
2. A distribution list (alias) to send email when they are created from a case
3. An email-to-case so that when an email is received at the alias, the case is created

This set up has two drawbacks:

1. It forces our employees to create a case to send an email to clients. If they send an email from the Account/Contact/Lead  activity history related list, the client will answer to their personal email and the other employees in the team won't be able to see it.
2. Our employees to put the alias in CC to keep the colleagues informed of communication with the clients, already this create a lot of fake cases that have to be closed

How do correctly configure Salesforce / which tools or extensions should we use to work effectively with outbound and inbound emails?